# Redirect after register wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a form that is created by the Tutor LMS plugin. It is a registration form.
I have a form that is created by the Tutor LMS plugin. It is a registration form.
I have a form that is created by the Tutor LMS plugin. It is a registration form.
sorry for typing that too many times, because I could not submit it cus the question has too many code and I had to type more.

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package TutorLMS/Templates
 * @version 1.4.3
 */

?>

<?php if ( ! get_option( 'users_can_register', false ) ) : ?>

    <?php
        $args = array(
            'image_path'  => tutor()->url . 'assets/images/construction.png',
            'title'       => __( 'Oooh! Access Denied', 'tutor' ),
            'description' => __( 'You do not have access to this area of the application. Please refer to your system  administrator.', 'tutor' ),
            'button'      => array(
                'text'  => __( 'Go to Home', 'tutor' ),
                'url'   => get_home_url(),
                'class' => 'tutor-button tutor-button-primary',
            ),
        );
        tutor_load_template( 'feature_disabled', $args );
        ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'tutor_before_instructor_reg_form' ); ?>

    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php do_action( 'tutor_instructor_reg_form_start' ); ?>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( tutor()->nonce_action, tutor()->nonce ); ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="tutor_register_instructor" name="tutor_action"/>

        <?php
            $errors = apply_filters( 'tutor_instructor_register_validation_errors', array() );
        if ( is_array( $errors ) && count( $errors ) ) {
            echo '<div class="tutor-alert-warning"><ul class="tutor-required-fields">';
            foreach ( $errors as $error_key => $error_value ) {
                echo '<li>' . $error_value . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul></div>';
        }
        ?>

        <div class="tutor-form-row">
            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'First Name', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'first_name' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'First Name', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="given-name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'Last Name', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'last_name' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Last Name', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="family-name">
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="tutor-form-row">

            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'User Name', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="text" name="user_login" class="tutor_user_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'user_login' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'User Name', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="username">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'E-Mail', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'email' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'E-Mail', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="email">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="tutor-form-row">
            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'Password', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'password' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Password', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="new-password">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tutor-form-col-6">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <label>
                        <?php _e( 'Password confirmation', 'tutor' ); ?>
                    </label>

                    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" value="<?php echo esc_attr( tutor_utils()->input_old( 'password_confirmation' ) ); ?>" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Password Confirmation', 'tutor' ); ?>" required autocomplete="new-password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
           /**
          * @since 2.8.1
          */
         if(class_exists('Edumall')){

              
               $privacy_page_id   = get_option( 'wp_page_for_privacy_policy', 0 );
         $privacy_link_html = esc_html__( 'Privacy Policy', 'edumall' );
               if ( $privacy_page_id ) {
                       $privacy_link_html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="edumall-privacy-policy-link" target="_blank">%2$s</a>',
                                esc_url( get_permalink( $privacy_page_id ) ),
                            $privacy_link_html
                   );
          }

          $terms_conditions_page_id   = Edumall::setting( 'page_for_terms_and_conditions', 0 );
          $terms_conditions_link_html = esc_html__( 'Terms', 'edumall' );
              if ( $terms_conditions_page_id ) {
                     $terms_conditions_link_html = sprintf( '<a href="%1$s" class="edumall-terms-conditions-link" target="_blank">%2$s</a>',
                           esc_url( get_permalink( $terms_conditions_page_id ) ),
                              $terms_conditions_link_html
                    );
           }
           }
           ?>
          <div class="form-group accept-account">
                        <label class="form-label form-label-checkbox" for="ip_accept_account">
                         <input type="checkbox" id="ip_accept_account" class="form-control"
                                     name="accept_account" required value="1">
                           <?php 
                                if(isset($privacy_link_html, $privacy_link_html)){
                         printf( esc_html__( 'Accept the %1$s and %2$s', 'edumall' ), $terms_conditions_link_html, $privacy_link_html ); 
                          }
                          ?>
                 </label>

                        <p>
                <label id="mc4wp-subscribe" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="mc4wp-subscribe" value="1" checked/>
                    اشترك فى نشرتنا البريدية.   
                </label>
                        </p>

          </div>
        <div class="tutor-form-row">
            <div class="tutor-form-col-12">
                <div class="tutor-form-group">
                    <?php
                        // providing register_form hook
                        do_action( 'tutor_instructor_reg_form_middle' );
                        do_action( 'register_form' );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'tutor_instructor_reg_form_end' ); ?>

        <div class="tutor-form-row">
            <div class="tutor-form-col-12">
                <div class="tutor-form-group tutor-reg-form-btn-wrap">
                    <button type="submit" name="tutor_register_instructor_btn" value="register" class="tutor-button"><?php _e( 'Register as instructor', 'tutor' ); ?></button>
                    [bws_google_captcha]
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>

    <?php do_action( 'tutor_after_instructor_reg_form' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want when someone registers successfully, it redirects them to another page.

How to do that? please advise me ..........

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a filter to set the redirect URL. Here is a snippet from the Developer Docs:

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $registration_redirect ) {
    return home_url();
}
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/registration_redirect/

Comment: I have two forms for registration, and this snippet will work for the two. I need it to work only for the above form only.